# Force tinymce editor on a structure that I provide?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm using the [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com) WYSIWYG Editor in my site to get user input. I want to define a Structure to be compared to user input, such as:

```
<div>
<h1></h1>
<h2></h2>
<article>
<div>
</div>
</article>
<h3></h3>
</div>
```

I need `tinymce` to prevent the user from typing any content that does not follow my structure. I don't know how to accomplish that, but I think there must be a way; can you explain how?

Comment: Mohemmad, I've edited your comment into the question, and attempted to clarify it. If I've made mistakes, please do re-edit it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: using the `<body>` tag this way is incorrect.**

Best option separate editors for the sections of the document.

TextField for H1 (title?)
TextField for H2 (subtitle)
WYSIWYG for the body copy (do not use the `<body>` tag) 
WYSIWYG for the footer

That's the common way to force content sections, then you would combine the data in your server-side code to display it exactly how you want it: think like a CMS.

If you want to go over-the-top front-end editable, make each editable inline. That would be best-case User Experience.

Comment: If you understood the question, would you mind editing it for the rest of us?

Comment: @Mogsdad what i mean by my question that i need the tinymce to prevent any content the user type if it's not follow my structure